# Go parsing JWT: error verifying ID token: illegal base64 data at input byte 0

Tags: javascript, authentication, go, jwt

I'm adding a Firebase JWT to my Google App Engine Go-service in the request header of a GET request. Here's the JavaScript:

```
const response = await fetch(
                'https://some-app.appspot.com/_ah/data', {
                    method: 'get',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + await Component.fetchJWT()
                    }
                });
```

On my Go service, which is hosted at the endpoint, the request is received. However, the error is thrown:

`error verifying ID token: illegal base64 data at input byte 0`

Here is how I process the JWT:

```
func (ma *myapp) SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    reqToken := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
    splitToken := strings.Split(reqToken, "Bearer")
    reqToken = splitToken[1]
    fmt.Println(reqToken) // Prints the token correctly

    lib.VerifyIDToken(ma.fbapp, reqToken) // Error is thrown in this function

    enc := json.NewEncoder(w)
    err := enc.Encode(SomeData)

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}
```

The token function is as such:

```
func VerifyIDToken(app *firebase.App, idToken string) *auth.Token {
    // [START verify_id_token]
    client, err := app.Auth(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error getting Auth client: %v\n", err)
    }

    token, err := client.VerifyIDToken(idToken)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error verifying ID token: %v\n", err) // Error thrown here
    }

    log.Printf("Verified ID token: %v\n", token)
    // [END verify_id_token]

    return token
}
```

When printing out the token, it appears fine to me. However, is my method of retrieving it from the request header wrong? It could appear so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the leading space in Authorization header split

```
strings.Split(reqToken, "Bearer ")
```

Comment: Hmm, then I get index out of range. Maybe I will take [0] then.

Comment: The JWT is getting passed in the request header, so that's not the issue

Comment: Can You show me how does the reqToken look like? Just anonymize the token

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Sorry.

Comment: fmt.Println(reqToken) before the split part and replace your token with something like "Bearer THISSHOULDBYMYTOKEN"  : )

Comment: Before: split `Bearer TOKEN`  , After split: `TOKEN`

Comment: If I go to jwt.io , it says my signature is invalid for token? :-/

Comment: Have you filled VERIFY SIGNATURE section (right bottom) on jwt.io with your token provider data?

Comment: It works now. I was passing the token wrong. It verifies token for each user now :)